# After creation NuGet package from package.nuspec issue with name of .nupkg

Tags: nuget, teamcity, azure-worker-roles, octopus-deploy

NuGet command:

```
E:\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NuGetRunner.exe
E:\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT\tools\NuGet.exe pack
E:\work\341fd6e3e508cc03\ETL\FgCloudServiceHost\package.nuspec -OutputDirectory
E:\work\341fd6e3e508cc03\ETL\FgCloudService\obj\octopacked -Version 17.02.18.1914-development -Properties Configuration=Release
```

and I have got

```
Successfully created package 'E:\work\341fd6e3e508cc03\ETL\JmineopsCloudService\obj\octopacked\fg.17.2.18.1914-development.nupkg'.
```

pay attention please on 17.02.18.1914-.....
 -Version 17.02.18.1914-development -Properties Configuration=Release
but after creation 17.2.18.1914-....
where is 0 ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Could you add a bit more details about your problem, since right now it's not quite clear what the problem is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version numbers used by NuGet follows [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/). The 'SemVer' specification includes the following:

> A normal version number MUST take the form X.Y.Z where X, Y, and Z are
>   non-negative integers, and **MUST NOT contain leading zeroes**.

So in other words the version number `17.02.18.1914-development` is normalized by NuGet.exe to `17.2.18.1914-development` (stripping the leading zero).

You have 'octopacked' (from OctoPack) in the path, so perhaps you would be interested in seeing a reply to a [similar question](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/29798-octopack-is-removing-leading-zeros-when-auto-creating-nuspec-file) in the Octopus Deploy support system.

Comment: Thanks mate. @Daniel Brixen